# Wikipedia image API search - contains total results + fileinfo

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

We want to build an image search based on Wikipedia Commons image database. I've experimented with different request formats but there seems to be no solution which fits 100% our needs.

What we want to achieve:

1. User search f.e. "Einstein"
2. We show them "808 results for Einstein found in Wikipedia"
3. Show them the first 10 results and allow a pagination

I tried:

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=%22Einstein%22&srnamespace=6
```

which returns the totals results (1842)

```
"query": {
    "searchinfo": {
        "totalhits": 1842
    },
```

and the results like:

```
{
    "ns": 6,
    "title": "File:Albert Einstein Head.jpg",
    "snippet": "DescriptionAlbert <span class=\"searchmatch\">Einstein</span> Head.jpg  English: Albert <span class=\"searchmatch\">Einstein</span> Fran\u00e7ais\u00a0: Portrait d'Albert <span class=\"searchmatch\">Einstein</span>  Date Copyrighted 1947, copyright not renewed. <span class=\"searchmatch\">Einstein</span>'s estate",
    "size": 968,
    "wordcount": 0,
    "timestamp": "2016-01-01T01:57:15Z"
}
```

But this response is missing a downloadable URL. For example the one of "File:Albert Einstein Head.jpg" is https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Albert_Einstein_Head.jpg

I would need to set another request to get the correct URLs by:

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=File:Albert Einstein Head.jpg|File:Einstein hair advice.jpg|File:Einstein - potpis.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url
```

Is there way to search for Wikipedia images which include their title, the URL to download and the total results (totalhits) in a single request?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the search query as a so called [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators), and then query the results of that generator for image url's using [`prop=imageinfo`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Imageinfo). In your case, it would look something like this:

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=Einstein&gsrprop=snippet&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&rawcontinue&gsrnamespace=6
```

`generator=search` tells the API to use this module as a generator. Arguments to this module is then prefixed `gsr`, like `gsrsearch=Einstein`, `gsrprop=snippet`, etc. Finally, `prop=imageinfo` works just like in a regular API query, but will be repeated for each result the generator returns.

**Related:**

- [How to get image URLs in different pages using a single WIKI api call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777792/how-to-get-image-urls-in-different-pages-using-a-single-wiki-api-call)
- [How to get image URL in wiki api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781455/how-to-get-image-url-in-wiki-api?lq=1)

Comment: Great @leo thx. Is there a way to get the "totalhits" together with the correct image response too?

Comment: According to this question the answer is no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997370/wikimedia-api-get-generator-metadata